# Get business details for CLIO?

Tags: rest, account, clio-api

I am integrating clio in my platfrom. I need to get the business details eg.name,id,platformid,address etc. from clio.

I have visited Clio documentation but there only `/users` API.

Please help me how can i get business details for CLIO ?

Answer (score 1):

The API does not provide Clio's business details. This page might have the information you're looking for: https://www.clio.com/contact/

If you're looking for the business details of user's law firm, some information is available through the `/users` endpoint [[docs]](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#operation/User#show). The nested field `account[name]` is the name of the law firm.